# Amazon S3: Cannot move document because of "All access to this object has been disabled"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was using this code for couple weeks,

```
config = {region: 'us-east-1',
          bucket: AWS_S3_CONFIG['bucket'],
          key:    AWS_S3_CONFIG['access_key_id'],
          secret: AWS_S3_CONFIG['secret_access_key']}
    Aws.config.update({region: config[:region], 
                       credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(config[:key], config[:secret]),
                       s3: { region: config[:region] }})

    bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(config[:bucket])

    object = bucket.object("document/#{document.user_id}/#{document.filename}")
    object.copy_from("#{config[:region]}/documents_temp/#{document.filename}", acl:'public-read')

    document.update_attribute(:file_s3_url, object.public_url)
```

but this morning when I tried to move a document within our system (and bucket), I've got an error saying:

```
All access to this object has been disabled
```

I didn't change anything in the app, anything in the Amazon AWS setup, this error just displayed.

What happened here? I am having difficulties to identify the issue.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you very much

Comment: Check your IAM and bucket policies.

Comment: I am looking at it and when click `Security Credentials`, there's a different access key than our app is using... How to figure this out? If I generate a new key, this key will not match the one we use in our app...